how to mock s3 using pytest? Unittest script calls actual function instead of mocking it?
I'm trying to test a function that should mock s3 resource but instead it tries to call the actual function.
Here is my code to test.
import sys
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import logging
import traceback
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import math
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import boto3



# conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('My App')
# sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# # Create a SparkSession from the SparkContext
# spark = SparkSession(sc)

# Initialize boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class Rivirproductlist:
    
    """  
    This class contains different functionalities to generate the access token,log and Fetch the Raw Json data 
    from Product Item Management list in Rivir API.
    
    """

    def __init__(
            self,
            ApplicationID,
            secret_name,
            region_name,
            batchsize,
            stageS3Bucket,
            logs3key,
            rootfolder,
            configs3key,
            s3Key

        ):
            
        
        """
        Constructor method to initialize class attributes.
        
        """

        # self.spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(ApplicationID).getOrCreate()
        self.ApplicationID = ApplicationID
        self.secret_name = secret_name
        self.region_name = region_name
        self.batchsize = int(batchsize)
        self.stageS3Bucket = stageS3Bucket
        self.logs3key = logs3key
        self.rootfolder = rootfolder
        self.configs3key = configs3key
        self.s3Key = s3Key

    def save_to_s3(self,bucket, key, json_data):
        
        """
        Function to save the raw data to S3
        
        """
        try:
            s3object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
            s3object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(json_data, indent = 2).encode('UTF-8'))))
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"failed to save in s3. Error:{e}")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # The arguments that include the glue job parameters.
    args = getResolvedOptions(
        sys.argv,
        [
         "ApplicationID",   
        "secret_name",
        "region_name",
        "batchsize",
        "stageS3Bucket",
        "logs3key",
        "rootfolder",
        "configs3key",
        "s3Key"
        ],
    )
    
    # Extracting and assigning the configuration options to variables.
    ApplicationID = args["ApplicationID"]
    secret_name = args["secret_name"]
    region_name = args["region_name"]
    batchsize = args["batchsize"]
    stageS3Bucket = args["stageS3Bucket"]
    logs3key = args["logs3key"]
    rootfolder = args["rootfolder"]
    configs3key = args["configs3key"]
    s3Key = args["s3Key"]
    
    # Creating an instance of Rivirproductlist with the specified configuration
    obj = Rivirproductlist(

        ApplicationID,
        secret_name,
        region_name,
        batchsize,
        stageS3Bucket,
        logs3key,
        rootfolder,
        configs3key,
        s3Key
    )
    
    # Execute the main processing function of the object
    obj.save_to_s3()

The code will be executed in an AWS glue job but I am testing it locally.
unittest script:
import unittest
#from unittest import  patch
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession , DataFrame
from s3_test  import Rivirproductlist  # replace with the actual module name
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from datetime import datetime
from moto import mock_aws
import pytest
from mock import patch


#sys.modules["awsglue.transforms"] = MagicMock()
#sys.modules["awsglue.utils"] = MagicMock() 

class TestRivirproductlist(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('pyspark.sql.SparkSession')
    def setUp(self, mock_spark):
        self.mock_spark = mock_spark
        self.rivirproductlist = Rivirproductlist(
            ApplicationID='test',
            secret_name='test_secret',
            region_name='us-west-2',
            batchsize=100,
            stageS3Bucket='test_bucket',
            logs3key='test_log',
            rootfolder='test_root',
            configs3key='test_config',
            s3Key='test_key'
        )

    @mock_aws
    def test_save_to_s3(self):
        # Given
        bucket = 'test_bucket'
        key = 'test_key'
        #self.s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket)

        # Initialize the Rivirproductlist object
        rivirproductlist = Rivirproductlist(
            ApplicationID='test',
            secret_name='test_secret',
            region_name='us-west-2',
            batchsize=100,
            stageS3Bucket='test_bucket',
            logs3key='test_log',
            rootfolder='test_root',
            configs3key='test_config',
            s3Key='test_key'
        )

        # When
        rivirproductlist.save_to_s3(bucket, key, {'key': 'value'})

        # Then
        response = self.s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        self.assertEqual(data, json.dumps({'key': 'value'}, indent=2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

When I give credential data then it gives me error:
AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

When I don't give credential then it gives
Unable to locate credentials
Why is it trying to execute the actual function instead of mocking the function?
When I give credential data in unittest script then it gives me error:
AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

When I don't give credential then it gives
Unable to locate credentials

possibly something is still talking to real AWS; make sure you've got the endpoint settings right.

running minio locally is one test option
adobe provide a mock s3 implementation: https://blog.developer.adobe.com/effectively-testing-our-aws-s3-utilization-using-the-s3mock-f139ebf81572

try the adobe one first: https://github.com/adobe/S3Mock
